# How to remove both duplicates in excel

Tags: excel

I have a list like the one in the screenshot below with two columns of data. I want to remove the duplicates in both columns. So in the example below, I need a method which detects and removes "Brian" from both column A and B.

How would I do this?

[image]

Comment: `I need a formula which detects and removes` - formula can't remove data from cell. You need VBA for this. Or you can higlight duplicates (but not remove) using conditional formatting

Comment: Ok, or I mean a method. For instance, when I want to remove duplicates while keeping one instance, I just sort by name, use "=A1=B1" in column C, drag down... sort by column C and remove all "true". That works, but I need a method to remove all instances when there is a duplicate while not even leaving the original.

Comment: something like this: `=COUNTIF(A:B,A1)>1`?

Comment: I don't quite understand that forumula. I don't mind combining the two columns and moving the data around by the way. The important thing is both brians dissapear from the spreadsheet.

Comment: ok, you can combine col A and col B in one column  (say col A). then use in C1 formula: = `=CountIf(A:A,A1)>1` - it returns `True` for all duplicates. Then filter only rows with `True` and remove them

Comment: or even simplier - combain values in column A and apply CF rule for duplicates (there is built-in conditional formatting rule for duplicates) say with red color. Then filter column A for red color and remove all visible rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tiny macro:

```
Sub DupRemover()
    Dim AB As Range, r As Range, cl As Collection
    Set AB = Range("A:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set cl = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In AB
        v = r.Value
        k = CStr(v)
        cl.Add v, k
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Err.Number = 0
            AB.Replace What:=v, Replacement:=""
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```